# When encoding the password, always return null value

Tags: java, password-encryption

I want to encode my password using an encryption key. but I got a null value, when printing the encoded password. I have attached my code below:

```
 public class FirstJava {
    
        private static final Long ENCRYPTION_KEY = 29190210908917L;     
                
        public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, byte[] key) {
            if (strToEncrypt == null)
                return strToEncrypt;
            try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
                final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
                return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes()));
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            return null;
        }

    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String password = "12345678";
            byte[] arr = String.valueOf(ENCRYPTION_KEY).getBytes();
            String passwordEnc = encrypt(password,arr);
            System.out.println("passwordEnc============= "+passwordEnc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `encrypt` method returns null when an exception occurs so that is most likely what happens: an exception. Helpfully if an exception occurs you write out "ERROR", so if you see this in the output this would be an indication that you really have an exception. Then the next step would be to find out what the exception is. For this you can write `exception.printStackTrace();` right in the catch block.

Comment: `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 14 bytes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES only supports key sizes of 16, 24 or 32 bytes. Your key length is 14, add 2 more digits to your key and it will work.

```
private static final Long ENCRYPTION_KEY = 2919021090891712L; //16 bytes
```